# when am running json api in Daml am getting this error?

Tags: daml

after starting sandbox and am running json api means am getting this error:

```
[http-json-ledger-api-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] ERROR com.digitalasset.http.HttpService$ - Cannot start se
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 4319876
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490)
        at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
        at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:507)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:627)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:515)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:686)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:675)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Dec 02, 2019 7:45:17 PM io.grpc.internal.AbstractClientStream$TransportState inboundDataReceived
INFO: Received data on closed stream
Dec 02, 2019 7:45:17 PM io.grpc.internal.AbstractClientStream$TransportState inboundDataReceived
INFO: Received data on closed stream

daml-helper: Received ExitFailure 101 when running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually due to too large messages being sent. You can try the `--max-inbound-message-size=...` parameter to specify a bigger limit. When using `daml start` you can use `daml start --json-api-option="--max-inbound-message-size=..."` to specify this option for the HTTP API.

Comment: we did this already,but ** we wanted to know what was the reason behind of this error**,because we have been tried this after restarting sandbox there is no data in sandbox,but we are receiving error memory exceeded.

Comment: The endpoint more prone to this kind of error is the package service, which allows to download the compiled packages from a running ledger. These packages tend to be quite large in non-trivial examples and the JSON API uses it to take decisions based on the types and templates defined in your package.

Comment: You should not experience this kind of error for very small packages. What threshold allowed you to make this work?

Comment: i made threshold around --max-inbound-message-size 4394304

Comment: That's very close to the default of `4194304` bytes. What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Daml sdk version is 0.13.36